# How do I refactor out HttpContext from AuthorizationFilterAttribute for testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I came across this code and wasn't able to test it as it references HttpContext. How do I remove the dependency on HttpContext to make this testable?

```
public class AuthorizeByUserStatus :AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly UserStatusEnum status;

    public AuthorizeByUserStatus(UserStatusEnum status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var authorize = false;
        var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
        var userIdentity = user.GetIdentity();

        if (userIdentity.UserStatus >= status)
        {
            authorize = true;
        }

        if (authorize)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the static HttpContext methods and reference the passed in actionContext which has the information we need!

```
var userIdentity = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.GetIdentity();
```

you can now pass in the actionContext with the correctly set Request details to get at the requesting users identity.